# Deploying codeigniter on heroku works fine on localhost but path issues on heroku

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, heroku

I am deploying a simple site on heroku that I make in codeigniter. It works perfectly fine on localhost (xampp), but not on heroku. On heroku it requires index.php and says that unable to load the model 'Core' and it is case sensitive too. What should I do?

When I run

> http://localhost/herokuroot/

My page loads but when I run

> https://bugdevroots.herokuapp.com/

It says

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

but it works for

> https://bugdevroots.herokuapp.com/index.php/Welcome

and my default controller is `welcome`

I have included this in my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

And in my config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have the same problem and this is how I solved it so far.

First, inside your `routes.php` you have to set your pages

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Assuming that inside your `views` folder you have a folder called `pages` that contains your pages in your site. After adding those in your `routes.php` go to your `autoload.php` inside the `config` folder and set the following codes:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

And then set the following codes into your `config.php` inside the `config` folder

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your_heroku_link';
$config['index_page'] = 'views/pages/home.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

In my `index_page'` is a file path where all of my pages are stored and `home.php` is where the page it will go once loaded.

Having set all of those just push it on your heroku

```
$ git push heroku master
```

and open up your app to see the results

```
$ heroku open
```

This might not be the right answer since I am still fixing on loading the css files in my app. But you can check out my codes on github if you need references: https://github.com/OariKirian/fy-stories-inc

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found a solution by deploying it first to my own server where I got the same error.
After some testing I found out that, as it was a linux server, case was sensitive!
So after renaming my controllers and model files with the first letter in capital, everything whas now ok.